# Changed R 4.0.0 text encoding behaviour?

Tags: r, encoder

I installed R 4.0.0 and now I am unable to open packages with the library function, however installing packages work just fine. See example with ggplot2:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")

WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/axehe47/OneDrive - Linköpings universitet/Dokument/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/ggplot2_3.3.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4015190 bytes (3.8 MB)
downloaded 3.8 MB

package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\axehe47\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgbP5K2\downloaded_packages
```

As you can see it installed the package properly into the directory but when I try to open the package with library I get this result:

```
library(ggplot2)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):
 cannot open file 'C:/Users/axehe47/OneDrive - LinkÃ¶pings universitet/Dokument/R/win-library/4.0/rlang/R/rlang.rdb': No such file or directory
```

Here the "ö" has changed to "Ã¶" which caused a "No such file or directory" error. It seems weird to me since install.packages doesn't show the same behaviour as library.

Furthermore, in Rmarkdown "å", "ä" and "ö" has changed characters which to me seems like they changed the text encoder (or what you call it), thus I wonder if I somehow can change how R encode text characters? Or is there something I can do to change this in any R settings?

It worked R 3.6.1 so I skimmed through the update news but didn't find anything relevant, but I could easily have missed something.

(ps. I ususally use Rstudio and have the default text encoding for saving set to ISO8859-1, this is not the issue. Also, I get the same behaviour for R and Rstudio)

Comment: You need to update [`Rtools`](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) to install packages from source.

Comment: You also may need to update RStudio to recognize the new Rtools.  I'd recommend installing packages outside of RStudio if that doesn't fix everything.

Comment: I installed Rtools and installed the package ggplot2 again, and as expected it did not change anything. TY. Did it in R, so RStudio is not to blame either.

Comment: The `ö` and other special characters might not be the best idea for directory names! Could you try to change that? Regardless, have you noticed the bottom part of the page my link refers to? There is another step to do. Might be related, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, maybe true that Ö is not good for paths, but it worked in R 3.6.1. I did the second step too.